# Draw a cylindrical volume

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw this image

[image]

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\definecolor{Darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
\draw (0,0) ellipse (0.7cm and 2.1cm);
%\draw (0cm,0cm) circle (2cm); 
%\draw (0cm,0cm) circle (3cm);

\draw (0,3) -- (3,4);
\draw (0,-3) -- (3,-2);

%% First clip 
\path[clip] (4cm,5cm) --  (4cm,-3cm) -- (-4,-3) -- (-4,5) -- cycle;
%%The circle 
%\node[circle,draw=black,minimum size=13cm] at (-10cm,1cm) (circ) {};

%\draw (3,4) arc (0:-30:13cm);
\draw (-9.5,1) circle (13cm);%This circle crosses desired points in a desired arc angle

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First of all I cannot realise the best way to draw the front side. I used ellipses and circles but I don't seem able to produce the same output. Secondly I can't find out how to make the arc on the right side be placed properly.

My ugly output is

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A pragmatic and semi-automated one...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=15]
\node[transform shape,ellipse,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=1cm,draw,outer sep=0] (a) {};
\clip[scale=0.8,postaction={line width=0.8pt,draw}] (a) circle (0.5 and 1);
\draw[scale=0.8] ([shift={($0.75*({cos(15)},{sin(15)})$)}]a) circle (0.5 and 1);
\draw(a.west) -- (a.east);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=15]
\draw (a.north) --  ++(0.75,0) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm-2\pgflinewidth) -- (a.south);
\draw (a.east) ++(0.75,0) -- ++(1cm,0) (a.west) ++(-0.75,0) -- ++(0.9cm,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit by Thanos:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\begin{scope}[rotate=15]
\node[transform shape,ellipse,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=1cm,draw,outer sep=0]     (a) {};
\clip[scale=0.8,postaction={line width=0.8pt,draw}] (a) circle (0.5 and 1);
\draw[scale=0.8] ([shift={($0.75*({cos(15)},{sin(15)})$)}]a) circle (0.5 and 1);
\draw(a.west) -- (a.east);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=15]
\draw (a.north) --  ++(0.75,0) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm-2\pgflinewidth) -- (a.south);
\draw[->] (a.east) ++(0.75,0) -- ++(1cm,0);
\draw (a.west) ++(-0.75,0) -- ++(0.9cm,0);
\node at (-1,0.2) {$\vec{V}$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (-0.17,0.72);
\draw[<-] (-0.2,0.92) -- (-0.2715,1.15);
\node[above] at (-0.272,1.15) {$db$};
\node[right] at (-0.09,0.36) {$b$};
\draw (0,1.05) -- (0.06,1.3);
\draw (0+0.8,1.05+0.02) -- (0.06+0.8,1.3+0.02);
\draw[<->] (0.03,1.175) -- (0.03+0.8,1.175+0.02);
\node[above] at (0.03+0.4,1.175+0.02) {$dx$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You must be joking! That's why you have 30k! This is awsome! Thank you very much! I could have never made it by my self! This output is extraordinary, beyond any imagination!!!Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Thanos Thank you for your kind words but I'm not sure if I got the perspective right. It's no more than eyeballing so this might need a more systematic approach if a more complex technical drawing is needed. I'm also not sure if I got the inner and outer lengths of the cylinder right or I need an ophthalmologist.  ;)

Comment: @percusse: I think it looks perfect.  But, do you have a link for the `postaction/clip` trickery. I don't think I have seen that before.

Comment: @percusse: No it'really perfect! I got lost in the code to be quite frank, but I tried to add the distances, not a flashy and sophisticated way like you and I got it to like a lot alike. Would you mind if I included the edited code and the output on my answer?

Comment: @Thanos Of course, that would be great. You can also accept your own answer if you feel that it's more complete.

Comment: @percusse:Of course not! I wouldn't dare to answer my own question after your perfect answer let alone accepting it. All I did was to add some lines and text;that's all. Actually I would suggest to give you the code so as to edit your answer.

Comment: @Thanos Please feel free to post your own answer or edit mine to include more details. creative commons rulaz :)

Comment: @percusse:I will edit yours since you game me permission!

Comment: For a small explanation to the hack that Peter mentioned in his comment:  It's just a reuse of the same path. First it clips so anything after that would be clipped including the next postaction. But when the draw action kicks in due to the previous clip, half of the line width is also clipped so I double the line width. So it's not a trick but rather an abuse :)

Comment: @percusse +1 for the explanation.