# How can I improve an eccentric annular plate figure via tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew a plate like the below picture
[image]

but I have two problem with it

1) The inner hole should be improved like the bellow picture (it have color and layer)
[image]

2) Also, a number of layers should be added to picture in thickness direction (like the below picture). it is good if I can change the color of each layer.
[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}‎
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0,0.77,1}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  coating/.style={fill=mycolor},
}
\def\angThe{40}
\def\angPhi{50}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\angThe}{\angPhi}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
  \def\R{1}     % radius of the inner plate
  \def\RR{2.2}  % outer radius
  \def\OC{1.5}  % Eccentricity of holes
  \def\z{1}     % thickness of the cake‎

  % translation vector between plates
  \coordinate (vert) at (0,0,\z); 
  \begin{scope}[shift={(vert)}]
    \draw [coating] (\RR,0) arc (0:360:\RR) -- (360:\OC) arc (360:0:\R) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \draw (\angPhi:-\RR) -- ++ (vert) 
         (\angPhi:\RR) -- ++ (vert);
  \draw(\RR,0) arc (0:-130:\RR);‎
    \draw(\RR,0) arc (0:50:\RR);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ti*k*Z is really not the right too for this .... At least, not the easiest/best. I have no idea what 'the laminated layer' refers to.

Comment: Laminated Layer: If in thickness direction we have three layer and each layer have a color.

Comment: Also, I have seen many beautiful circular plate via Tikz. like as  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385943/illustrating-drawing-in-3d-using-tikz/385950     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off

Comment: The only way I can count layers is that there are 6, but I don't know which is laminated.

Comment: OK, my mean is the number of layer in thickness direction. I will edit the question now.

Comment: The first link is to an enormous list. The second is relevant, sure, but what's your point? You can do this in Ti*k*Z. It just isn't a good tool for it. Your picture is 3D and has lighting effects. 3D can be faked in 2D, but it isn't native. Lighting can be faked-ish, but you have to explicitly shade for it - there's no concept of a light source.

Comment: I do not want shading effect. Just I want draw the figure.

Comment: If I were you, I'd start with the [washer of asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/washer.asy).

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you with a start point https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80224/125434

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If realism isn't a desiderata, you might try something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,2,4,...,15}
  {
    \scoped[yshift=\i mm] \draw [draw=blue!10!black, preaction={fill=blue!50!cyan, even odd rule}, left color=black, right color=black, middle color=white, shading=axis, opacity=.5, even odd rule] circle (5 and 3) circle (2.5 and 1.5);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacked disk-ish things]

Now for some colour ...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% xcolor manual: 34
\definecolorseries{colours}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{colours}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,2,4,...,25}
  {
    \color{colours!!+}
    \scoped[yshift=\i mm] \draw [draw=blue!10!black, preaction={fill, even odd rule}, left color=black, right color=black, middle color=white, shading=axis, opacity=.5, even odd rule] circle (5 and 3) circle (2.5 and 1.5);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured disk-ish things]

If you want to `xshift` the inner circles by, say, 5mm, just use a coordinate before cutting out the inner circle. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% xcolor manual: 34
\definecolorseries{colours}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{colours}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,2,4,...,25}
  {
    \color{colours!!+}
    \scoped[yshift=\i mm] \draw [draw=blue!10!black, preaction={fill, even odd rule}, left color=black, right color=black, middle color=white, shading=axis, opacity=.5, even odd rule] circle (5 and 3) (5mm,0) circle (2.5 and 1.5);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured disk-ish things with shifted cut-outs]

## EDIT

Here's a customisable version which also shows how to vary the shading angle to gesture towards differently positioned light sources (sort of).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% xcolor manual: 34
\definecolorseries{colours}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{colours}
\tikzset{
  stacked layers/.search also={/tikz},
  stacked layers/.cd,
  layers/.store in=\layersno,
  shading angle/.store in=\layerssa,
  layer height/.store in=\layersht,
  outline/.code={
    \colorlet{layers outline colour}{#1}
  },
  outer circle/x/.store in=\layersocx,
  outer circle/y/.store in=\layersocy,
  outer circle/.code args={#1 and #2}{
    \tikzset{
      stacked layers/outer circle/.cd,
      x=#1,
      y=#2,
    }%
  },
  inner circle/x/.store in=\layersicx,
  inner circle/y/.store in=\layersicy,
  inner circle/.code args={#1 and #2}{
    \tikzset{
      stacked layers/inner circle/.cd,
      x=#1,
      y=#2,
    }%
  },
  inner circle/x shift/.store in=\layersicshiftx,
  inner circle/y shift/.store in=\layersicshifty,
  inner circle shift/.code args={#1 and #2}{
    \tikzset{
      stacked layers/inner circle/.cd,
      x shift=#1,
      y shift=#2,
    }%
  },
  colours set/.code={
    \resetcolorseries[#1]{colours}%
  },
  layers/.forward to=/tikz/stacked layers/colours set,
  layers=12,
  outer circle=5 and 3,
  inner circle=2.5 and 1.5,
  inner circle shift=0pt and 0pt,
  shading angle=90,
  outline=blue!10!black,
  layer height=2mm,
  /tikz/.cd,
  stack layers/.pic={
    \tikzset{
      stacked layers/.cd,
      #1,
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\layerssteps{int((2*\layersno)+1)}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\layersno}
    {
      \color{colours!![\i]}
      \scoped[yshift=\i*\layersht] \draw [draw=layers outline colour, preaction={fill, even odd rule}, left color=black, right color=black, middle color=white, shading=axis, shading angle=\layerssa, opacity=.5, even odd rule] circle ({\layersocx} and {\layersocy}) (\layersicshiftx,\layersicshifty) circle ({\layersicx} and {\layersicy});
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {stack layers};
  \pic at (9,0) {stack layers={layers=20, shading angle=115, outline=gray, layer height=3mm, outer circle=4 and 2.5, inner circle=2.75 and 1.8, inner circle shift=5mm and 2.5mm}};
  \pic at (4.5,-6) {stack layers={layers=15, shading angle=125, inner circle shift=-5mm and 0pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacked layers variations]

`stack layers` is a `pic` which accepts one optional argument. If used, this argument should consist of key-value pairs to be passed to `\tikzset`. The following keys are recognised. Other keys will be passed to Ti*k*Z and may or may not have any effect and may or may not give weird results. Default values are given in parentheses.

- `layers=<positive integer>` specifies the number of layers (`12`);
- `layer height=<dimension>` specifies the height of each layer (`2mm`);
- `outer circle=<x> and <y>` specifies the width and height of the outer border of each layer (`5 and 3`);
- `inner circle=<x> and <y>` specifies the width and height of the inner border of each layer (`2.5 and 1.5`);
- `inner circle shift=<x> and <y>` specifies the horizontal and vertical offset of the inner border of each layer (`0pt and 0pt`);
- `shading angle=<angle in degrees>` specifies the angle of the shading (`90`);
- `outline=<colour>` specifies the angle used to draw the outline of each layer.

The colours used to fill the layers are derived from the colour series `colours` (as before) and the number of layers. So if there are more layers, the colours will change more slowly from layer to layer; fewer layers means fewer colours and more rapid changes.

Comment: Tank you, it is very nice. just It is possible to xshift the inner circles?

Comment: @sayros Like this? ^^

Comment: Ok,Tank you , that is right.

Comment: @sayros Please see edit above for a `pic` version which allows you to tweak various things more easily.

Answer (score 3):

It is rather straightforward to draw something of that sort.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red!40] (0,0) circle [x radius=4,y radius=1];
\fill[red!40] (-4,0) rectangle (4,1);
\draw[fill=blue!40] (0,1) circle [x radius=4,y radius=1];
\fill[blue!40] (-4,1) rectangle (4,2);
\draw[fill=red!40] (0,2) circle [x radius=4,y radius=1];
\fill[red!40] (-4,2) rectangle (4,3);
\draw[fill=blue!40] (0,3) circle [x radius=4,y radius=1];
\fill[blue!40] (-4,3) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[fill=red!40] (0,4) circle [x radius=4,y radius=1];
\fill[red!40] (-4,4) rectangle (4,5);
\draw[fill=blue!40] (0,5) circle [x radius=4,y radius=1];
\fill[blue!40] (-4,5) rectangle (4,6);
\draw[fill=blue!50] (0,6) circle [x radius=4,y radius=1];
\draw[fill=blue!65] (0.5,5.75) circle [x radius=2,y radius=0.5];
\pattern[pattern=vertical lines] (0.5,5.75) circle [x radius=2,y radius=0.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]